# CSS Touch Ripple Effect, Not Working Properly

Tags: html, css, click, touch

My CSS touch ripple is not working properly. It is just seen like a bubble in the center when i click on the button. Please help in finding where am i doing the mistake. i am not much known to CSS animations. i would like to do this using just CSS only.

```css
.ripple-con,
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button::after,
.ripple {
  content: ' ';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.button:active::after,
.ripple:active,
.button:active+.ripple {
  animation: ripple 2s;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}

.button {
  line-height: 39px;
  border: 0;
  height: 42px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  vertical-align: top;
}

html {
  text-align: center
}

body {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple-con">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit Button : Button">
  <span class="ripple"></span>
</div>

<div class="ripple-con">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Input Button : Button">
  <span class="ripple"></span>
</div>

<div class="button">Div : Button</div>

<button class="button">Button : Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place `animation: ripple` inside `.button::after, .ripple` style definition and place `animation: none` where it goes active as follows

```css
.ripple-con,
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button::after,
.ripple {
  content: ' ';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: ripple 2s;
}

.button:active::after,
.ripple:active,
.button:active + .ripple {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}

.button {
  line-height: 39px;
  border: 0;
  height: 42px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: default;
  vertical-align: top;
}

html {
  text-align: center
}

body {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple-con">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit Button : Button">
  <span class="ripple"></span>
</div>

<div class="ripple-con">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Input Button : Button">
  <span class="ripple"></span>
</div>

<div class="button">Div : Button</div>

<button class="button">Button : Button</button>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2rpe8tr/1/)